# An example of the file structure dbf

Tags: database, data-structures, foxpro, dbf

I have a short example on how to generate dbf files like

I saw the following link:
[Data File Header Structure for the dBASE Version 7 Table File](http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm)

I write my program with C #

For example, I want to produce the following table( to binary ):

```
Field Name  Type        MaxLength
-------------------------------------------
DSK_ID      Character   100
DSK_ADRS    Numeric     2
```

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @JimMischel How do I generate content Dbf File?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to create the table within Foxpro (Visual Foxpro) itself?, DBase, or with a .net/java language.  Your tabs are unclear as to what you are really getting into, and just creating the table via low-level is not the way to go.

I can modify this answer more, but suggest you edit your question to provide more detail.

The basic syntax, if using Visual FoxPro would be something like.

```
create table SomeTableName ( DSK_ID C(100), DSK_ADRS  N(2,0) )
```

But again, would need more on the environment you plan on working with.

By knowing you want to do via C#, I would start by [Downloading Microsoft's VFP OleDb provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839).

Then, you can look at the many other links for connecting, querying (always parameterize) and execute what you need.  Here is a short example to get a connection and create the table you want.  Then it is up to you for querying, inserting, updating as needed.

```
OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\\SomePath");
OleDbCommand oCmd = new OleDbCommand();
oCmd.Connection = oConn;
oCmd.Connection.Open();
oCmd.CommandText = "create table SomeTableName ( DSK_ID C(100), DSK_ADRS  N(2,0) )";
oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();         
oConn.Close();
```

Now, note, the "Connection" string has a Data Source.  This should point to a PATH location where you WANT TO CREATE and/or QUERY the tables.  You can have one connection that points to a folder that has 100+ tables and you can eventually query from any of them.  But again, those are going to be other questions that you can find LOTS of answer to for sampling... for example, just search on

VFP OleDB C# and you will get plenty of hits

Comment: I want to create content of dbf file without foxpro by c#

Comment: @javadaskari, revised answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to handle memo files? Compound index files?

Just use the ODBC or Ole DB providers via COM InterOp and issue a CREATE TABLE.